# VS Code - запуск из терминала

Tags: windows, консоль, visual-studio-code

Какие ключи/флаги нужно использовать, чтобы открыть с консоли VS Code в текущей директории ?

Т.е., просто произвести запуск с консоли получается - `code` - и все работает. Но при это открывается пустой документ (что ожидалось, но не есть цель). Хотелось бы, используя *некий* ключ/флаг при запуске из под консоли, открыть в VS Code текущую директорию.

---

ОС: Windows (*на тот случай, если вышесказанное мной возможно, но для nix/Windows эти ключи разные*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если заглянуть в реестр

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\VSCode\command
```

то можно найти команду

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "%V"
```

Соответственно для консоли команда получится

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .
```

что, вообще-то, совсем неудивительно.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает !

Answer (score 3):

нужно писать `code .`, т.е. добавить в конце точку

Comment: чем же суть вашего ответа отличается от изложенного в двух других ответах?

Comment: В самом деле, это же не бессрочная викторина. Зачем дублировать ответы?!

Comment: Да в том что, предыдущие ответы размазываю ... по столу.
А тут четкий ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы открыть в редакторе текущую папку напиши в консоли: "code ."
Или "code index.html", например, чтобы открыть файл в текущей папке.